# Detect 360 degrees turn algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, rotation, accelerometer

I'm successfully detecting 0-360 degrees rotation (roll) of phone around an axis, but now I am having hard times designing an effective algorithm to detect one full turn. My working but I think not elegant and as effective algorithm as I would like is:

```
private boolean detectRoll;
private boolean[] checkpointsR = new boolean[4];
private boolean fullRollTurn;

public void detectingRoll() {
    setDetectRoll(true);
    checkpointsR[0] = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (roll > 90 * i && roll < 90 * (i + 1)
            && checkpointsR[i - 1] == true) {
            checkpointsR[i] = true;
        }
    }

    if (areAllTrue(checkpointsR) && roll > 0 && roll < 45) {
        fullRollTurn = true;
        // reset rollCheckpoints
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            checkpointsR[i] = false;
        }
    }
}

public static boolean areAllTrue(boolean[] array) {
    for (boolean b : array)
        if (!b)
            return false;
    return true;
}

public void setDetectRoll(boolean detectRoll) {
    this.detectRoll = detectRoll;
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This code has constant time complexity (O(1)) as you only iterate over your 4 checkpoints whatever happens, so unless you've done some profiling that tells you it's a bottleneck I think that the gain of optimizing this would be negligable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking for any new suggestions, not the optimization of my algorithm since I know it's not as it should be.

Comment: If it's working, yet you don't want optimization, what *do* you want? "Suggestions" is pretty broad, and will most likely get it closed.

Comment: The question says it wasn't effective yet at full 360 degree turns. The expectation though is why can't you just add up smaller turns?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code only detects turns that result from increasing `roll`. In the other direction, ie a turn resulting from `roll` falling,

```
    if (checkpointsR[i - 1] == true) 
    {
        checkpointsR[i] = true; 
    }
```

won't ever trigger.

While that's easily fixable, if the only sensor input you've got is `roll`, the fixed-checkpoint is approach always going to have problems. The best way to visualize it is that your checkpoints are little red points on a circle, and the rotation of the phone corresponds to an ant crawling around the edge of the circle. Suppose that when the ant passes a point, it turns green, and that this represents the checkpoint being set to `true`. If the ant starts between two checkpoints `A` and `B`, it can "fool" them by crawling through `B`, all the way round to `A`, and then turning around and heading the other way again. All the checkpoints will be green, but the ant won't have completed a full circle.

The way to resolve this is to change two things: first, give the checkpoints three states: `unvisited`, `clockwise` and `anticlockwise`. Second, **start the ant on top of a checkpoint**.

Here're the new rules:

- Every point starts as `unvisited` (a red point).
- If the ant passes a checkpoint in a clockwise direction, set it's state to `clockwise` (a little green arrow pointing clockwise from the point)
- If the ant passes a checkpoint in the anticlockwise direction, set it's state to `anticlockwise` (a little green arrow pointing on the anticlockwise direction from the point)
- A turn has been completed if all the checkpoints are `clockwise` or if they're all `anticlockwise`.

This can be achieved with three checkpoints, and placed wherever you want on the circle as long as the first one is under the ant's initial position. I'd recommend `{initial, inital + 120, initial + 240}` though for symmetry's sake.

(The ant thought-experiment works with two checkpoints, but when you've got two checkpoints the problem is there are a pair a regions with a non-unique checkpoint between them, which confuses the detection of which checkpoint the ant actually passed through when the ant goes from one region to the other)

Comment: Can you help me out on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997669/android-acceleration-down-smash) please?